# Aggregate yearly spend of user based on billing cycle (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to track the yearly spend of users based on a particular month from which we start their cycle. This is to keep track of their yearly spend so that they don't exceed the allowed limits. I have the following two tables:

Spend (Contains 1 row per user per month) (I can modify the date column of this table to any date format as needed, if it helps):

```
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| ID | Date      | Year | Month | Spend |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Sep-19 | 2019 | 9     | 10    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Oct-19 | 2019 | 10    | 23    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Nov-19 | 2019 | 11    | 27    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Dec-19 | 2019 | 12    | 14    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Jan-20 | 2020 | 1     | 13    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Feb-20 | 2020 | 2     | 33    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Mar-20 | 2020 | 3     | 25    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Apr-20 | 2020 | 4     | 17    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-May-20 | 2020 | 5     | 14    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Jun-20 | 2020 | 6     | 10    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Jul-20 | 2020 | 7     | 46    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Aug-20 | 2020 | 8     | 53    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Sep-20 | 2020 | 9     | 38    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Oct-20 | 2020 | 10    | 22    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 11 | 01-Nov-20 | 2020 | 11    | 29    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 50 | 01-Jul-20 | 2020 | 7     | 56    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 50 | 01-Aug-20 | 2020 | 8     | 62    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 50 | 01-Sep-20 | 2020 | 9     | 77    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 50 | 01-Oct-20 | 2020 | 10    | 52    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| 50 | 01-Nov-20 | 2020 | 11    | 45    |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-------+
```

Billing Cycle (contains the months between which we calculate their total spends):

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| ID  | StartMonth | EndMonth |
+-----+------------+----------+
| 11  | 10         | 9        |
+-----+------------+----------+
| 50  | 9          | 8        |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

Sample Output:

```
+----+-------+------------+
| ID | Cycle | TotalSpend |
+----+-------+------------+
| 11 | 1     | 10         |
+----+-------+------------+
| 11 | 2     | 313        |
+----+-------+------------+
| 11 | 3     | 51         |
+----+-------+------------+
| 50 | 1     | 118        |
+----+-------+------------+
| 50 | 2     | 174        |
+----+-------+------------+
```

In the sample output, for ID = 11, cycle 1 indicates spend in Sep'19, cycle 2 indicates total spend from Oct'19 (Month 10) to Sep'20 (Month 9) and cycle 3 indicates total spend for the next 12 months from Oct'20 (till whichever month data is present).

I'm a beginner to SQL and I believe doing this might require the use of CTE/Subqueries. Would appreciate any help or guidance for this.

Comment: @DaleK You are right. I've just started learning SQL a couple of days back and was wondering if there might be some functions or techniques for solving such problems that I'm not aware of yet. My knowledge is limited only till Joins for now and I'm just getting started on subqueries. I wasn't able to figure out a way using the aggregation techniques I've come across. Nevertheless, I'll give it a shot and hopefully will add an attempt here within a day or so.

Comment: Your sample seems wrong. The ID 11 Cycle 3 should have a TotalSpend of 51, not 29.

Comment: @Lucero You're right. I've made the edit to indicate the correct value

Comment: Something is wrong with this data.  The cycles seem like they should be based on dates, not month numbers.  I would start by fixing the data, so `JOIN` can be used more simply.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Basically the Billing Cycle defines at which month the cycle starts for each ID. It is therefore not an expanded view of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be an exercise of some sort, I'm not going to provide a full answer, but give you hints to how this could be solved conceptually.

First I think you should associate entries to effective cycles (with cycle number) for the required date range. This could be done by using a recursive CTE. These are not the most efficient approach, but since we don't have the effective cycles with their numbers as a distinct table it can be a working solution nevertheless.

The result then just needs to be grouped by the ID and cycle number and the amounts summed up, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'd have to read up on CTEs to fully grasp your suggestion. The assignment of cycle number is what I can't get my head around.

Comment: Let's focus on just one ID to understand the process. First we should identify the very first Spend entry (e.g. the one with the lowest date), which will be Cycle 1. From there on, we go to the next entry (with recursion) and check whether it is still in the same BillingCycle. If not, the Cycle needs to be increased by one. Do this until you've reached the last entry. This is what we then group by Cycle. Note: * I usually take a ROW_NUMBER() window function to number items. * Your data has some redundancy in it (Spend: Date <> Month+Year; BillingCycle: StartMonth implies EndMonth) #!18/74588/3

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I hadn't come across the window function earlier and hence wasn't aware of how to number the entries. I'll give this a shot after reading up on it.